# celluloid task was terminated

Tags: ruby, guard, celluloid

When using Guard, I get the following error when running `bundle exec guard` under cygwin. I can't seem to find much on this error other than this issue:

[stack level too deep (SystemStackError) · Issue #172 · guard/listen · GitHub](https://github.com/guard/listen/issues/172)

Does anybody know the cause? Or whether Guard works under cygwin at all?

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:32:in `terminate': task was terminated (Celluloid::Task::TerminatedError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:404:in `block in cleanup'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:404:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:404:in `cleanup'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:375:in `shutdown'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:367:in `handle_crash'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:187:in `rescue in run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:171:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:157:in `block in initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/thread_handle.rb:13:in `block in initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/internal_pool.rb:100:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/internal_pool.rb:100:in `block in create'
    from (celluloid):0:in `remote procedure call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:92:in `value'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/proxies/sync_proxy.rb:33:in `method_missing'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-2.7.4/lib/listen/listener.rb:131:in `_init_actors'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-2.7.4/lib/listen/listener.rb:38:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.4.0/lib/guard/commander.rb:30:in `block in start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.4.0/lib/guard/commander.rb:108:in `block in within_preserved_state'
    from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.4.0/lib/guard/commander.rb:105:in `within_preserved_state'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.4.0/lib/guard/commander.rb:26:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.4.0/lib/guard/cli.rb:101:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.4.0/bin/guard:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/guard:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/guard:23:in `<main>'
```

My Guardfile:

```
guard 'rspec' do
  # watch /lib/ files
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+).rb$}) do |m|
    "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"
  end

  # watch /spec/ files
  watch(%r{^spec/(.+).rb$}) do |m|
    "spec/#{m[1]}.rb"
  end
end
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide your class where the celluloid is used? Please also check log/test.log as it may contain logs about crash in code. When you are using celluloid it does not report everything to the stdout in specs.

Comment: This seems to be very old. Are you still experiencing this problem?